# How to handle Access DataSheetView selection change event..?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

I have a Form with Default View Split Form enabled, so it will appear like picture below every time it loaded.
[image]

I also enable the page header to appear at the top which has a label to store some value (It will store Diff Amount value). What I want to do is, everytime user click on the datasheet view (and make record selection change or cell change) below the form header, I want to update the value of my label on the form header.
It's easy to change the value, but how to handle the datasheet view record selection, or datasheet view cell selection change.
In Excel, this is very easy to do, we can handled it from Worksheet.SelectionChange event, but how to do this in Access...?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see the pic from where I work, but I am quite sure you can use the form `OnCurrent` event.

Comment: It's work, thank you very much Patrick, I really appreciate it...:).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the form `OnCurrent` event, which fires whenever a new record becomes `Current`

Comment: Yes...It solve my problem. Why don't they named it OnControlSelectionChanged or OnRecordSelectionChanged...?

Comment: I put it as a response so you Accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)